# Putting a list into a class c#

Tags: c#, list

Is it possible to put a list into a class? So for example if I have a class of Person and their properties are Name, Age, Valuables can the Valuables property be a list that holds a Valuable class with properties like ItemName, Cost, Quantity?

Comment: @FelixD. you mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8 (your link was in German).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!

You would just have

```
public class Person {
     string Name;
     int Age;
     List<Valuable> Valuables = new List<Valuable>();
}

public class Valuable {
    string ItemName;
    double Cost;
    int Quantity;
}
```

to use the code, you would then

```
Person bob = new Person { Name = "Bob", Age = 29 };
Valuable bobsCrystalBall = new Valuable { ItemName = "CrystalBall", Cost = 9.99, Quantity = 1}
bob.Valuables.Add(bobsCrystalBall);
```

@SomeBody should have specified that you can't do `Person.Valuables.Add` directly, you have to do that on an instance of that class. You create an instance of a class with the keyword `new`. Similarly with adding an instance of the class `Valuable`.

Comment: And so to add to the list would be Person.Valuable.Add() etc?

Comment: Excellent answer and the only thing I was missing was the instantiation of the list in the class! Couldn't figure it out but thank you for helping and explaining further!

Comment: @Matt Probably a good idea to initialise `Valuables` before using `.Add`?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
     public List<ValuablesDTO> Valuables {get;set;}

     public  class ValuablesDTO
     {
          public string ItemName {get;set;}
          public decimal Quantity {get;set;}
          public decimal Cost {get;set;}
      }
}
```